# How do I authenticate with couchdb using couchbeam?

Tags: authentication, erlang, couchdb

I'm trying to create a database in couchdb, which has an admin user/password set, using couchbeam. I've set my credentials in couchdb's local.ini file and restarted. My code to create a db is:

```
couchbeam:start(),
Params = #couchdb_params{username="test" ,password="pass"},
Connection = couchbeam_server:start_connection_link(Params),
Db = couchbeam_db:create(Connection, "testdb")
```

At this point Db = {unknown_error, 401}. Am I doing something wrong here? The 401 seems to indicate an authentication error.

My username/password are ok as this works from the command line:

```
$curl -X PUT http://test:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/testdb
{"ok":true}
```

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10, couchdb 0.10.0. couchbeam 0.4.1, Erlang R1301. Any ideas?

Comment: Try the following trace commands in your console: `dbg:tracer().`, `dbg:tpl(couchbeam_server, '_', [{'_', [], [{return_trace}]}]).`, `dbg:p(all, c)`. ? The debug output after calling couchbeam_db:create() might lead you towards the problem.

Comment: A difference between the two cases is that couchbeam uses the HTTP Authorization header, while curl passes authentication via the URL. Could this be a server configuration problem ?

Comment: I ran the trace bit it didn't reveal any additional details. The 401 is coming back from couchdb. Any idea how to configure couchdb to take HTTP Authorization header (can it do this)?

Comment: I got a little further. With the correct username/pass I get back:
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
By changing to an invalid password I get:
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
So maybe this is some couchdb bug or the auth header is wrong or unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug with couchbeam. It has been [fixed](http://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam/commit/c3f4a12b3481d455a01049f28d949c17f2d868de) and the fix published to [github](http://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam).

Comment: Accept your answer so people will know this question is closed.

Comment: Will do - but SO makes you wait 24h before accepting your own answer... so you'll have to wait at least another 6 hours.